# Exception while running mobile automation script with Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am doing mobile automation on Android with Appium and JAVA-selenium. When I execute the script I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: ) (WARNING: 
The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 25.69 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-1M92PA5', ip: '192.168.0.103', os.name: 'Windows 
10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:156)
at Appium.AppiumSetupPage.setUp(AppiumSetupPage.java:43)
at Appium.C8_Java.main(C8_Java.java:10)
```

What could be possible reason for this?

Comment: Could you please create a minimal example that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Hi, please share the code you tried and the Appium error logs. Appium logs have the exact error details.